# Python Flask - while clicking submit button it returns the login page instead of returning 'login sucessful' (MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, authentication, flask

I'm really new to this stuff. So I'm sorry if this is a silly question. I don't even know if the code is correct I didn't follow a proper tutorial for the login part. So the code basically just returns the login page when clicking the submit button. Registering a new account works perfectly fine but when I login to the account that I just registered, it does this. What am I doing wrong?

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import uuid

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "abcd"
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'Root123'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'login'

mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'loginUsername' in request.form and 'loginPassword' in request.form:
            loginUsername = request.form['login_username']
            loginPassword = request.form['login_password']
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM logininfo WHERE Username=%s AND Password=%s", (loginUsername, loginPassword))
            loginInfo = cursor.fetchone()
            if loginInfo['Username'] is loginUsername and loginInfo['Password'] is loginPassword:
                return 'Login successful!'
            else:
                return 'Login unsuccessful'

    return render_template("login.html")


@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userDetails = request.form
        username = userDetails['register_username']
        email = userDetails['register_email']
        password = userDetails['register_password']
        userID = str(uuid.uuid4())
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO logininfo(username, email, password, userID) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (username, email, password, userID))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template("register.html")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**login.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Login Page {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form action="#" method="POST">
    <p> Username: </p>
    <input type="text" name="login_username" />
    <p></p> Password: </p>
    <input type="password" name="login_password"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for msg in messages %}
                    <p>{{msg}}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Here is the MySQL table that I am using:**

[image]

Comment: This does not answer you question, but do not compare strings with `is`, use `==`.

Comment: have you checked if you are getting to the part where you are checking for username and password?

Comment: what does it return